# Using python to move files with common phrase/number in the name to a file with the same number then increasing the number and repeating

Tags: python, move

I have a folder full of files named `Stack_1` up till `Stack_30`. I get these files all in a folder like this often so wanted to make a script to organize them into folders.

Each Stack has 4 files so it will be `Stack_1.txt`, `Stack_1_shifts.txt` and so on.

I tried making a script using `shutil.move` but it doesn't like it when I don't use the absolute name of something:

```
import os
import shutil
n = 1
while (n < 30):
    shutil.move('Stack_'n*, 'stack_'n)
    n = n+1
```

I have already made the folders. Any advice on how to do this in an automated fashion would be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed the indentation check if it's correct. Can you make your question more clear? What is the current folder structure and what is your desired output.

Comment: Have you tried string substitution?  Like this: `shutil.move('Stack_%d' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))`.  I'm not sure what the `n*` is all about, because you aren't multiplying it by anything.

Answer (score 0):

the issue/title is kind of confusing, but i will try to do my best to help ya.

from my understanding you have a folder with files

['stack_1', 'stack_2',..., 'stack_30']

Each of those files are actually 4, stack_1 would be:

'stack_1','stack_1_shift','stack_1_X','stack_1_Y'

And you want to move em to four folders, folders:

'regular','shift','X','Y'.

I am hoping that is it, if so, here is how you solve it:

folders_name_array = ['stack','shift','x', 'y']

`for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
           if file.endswith('shift'):
                 os.move (file, destination)
           elif file.endswith('X'):
                  os.move (file, destination2) 
           so on..`

Answer (score 0):

yesss string substitution worked sorry im not great with python so was using * for wildcard.

in the end

```
import os
import shutil

n = 1

while (n < 30):
shutil.move('Stack_%d.txt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
shutil.move('Stack_%d_shifts.txt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
shutil.move('Stack_%d.mrc' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))
shutil.move('Stack_%d.rawtlt' % (n), 'stack_%d' % (n))

n = n+1
```

worked